# responsive.recalc on divs changing from "display: none" to "display: block"

Tags: javascript

I have some div's that are not displayed on page load.

They become visible on button press, but when they are displayed, they do not fit properly in their position until the window has been resized.

I've read that this is because they did not have a width on page load.

I'm running a `responsive.recalc()` line to try and get the div to sit straight into where it needs to go but it's not working.

```
function clearfilter(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
       e.style.display = 'block';
       e.responsive.recalc();
}
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: `responsive.recalc()` isn't standard DOM api, what libraries are you using?

Comment: as far as I know I'm not using any Libraries, I'm guessing that's the problem

Comment: It looks like it's part of ["DataTables"](https://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc). If that is being used, maybe look through the docs?

Comment: is there anything without libraries to preform this action?

Comment: I'd need more some more context. Could you try building a cut-down example with https://jsfiddle.net/ (or similar) to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Here is a link to the page i'm working on. it's in squarespace so I don't have complete control for the code but I'm working of the filter projects buttons https://jac-group.squarespace.com/test-filter

Comment: I can't see where the code is on your site to fix (and don't have time to debug your site). Cutting the problem down in jsfiddle will help you understand the problem and make it easier for others to help you.